# difference between while and do while loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops

can anybody tell me the basic difference (in terms of efficiency) between the while loop and do while loop in `c++` ?
I tried to search it through web but couldn't find the exact answer.

Comment: I don't see a duplicate here.

Comment: There used to be a joke about yachts "If you have to ask the price, you can't afford it".  In this situation:  If you have to ask the efficiency difference, you aren't going to write efficient enough code for that tiny difference to matter.  I answered anyway.   But this comment might be more informative than that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in terms of efficiency. Both amount to a condition evaluation and a conditional jump.

Comment: Yes, and if you're wondering why they have both methods, it because some tasks *need* to satisfy a condition in order to be done. For example, you'd want to check for eof before attempting to read a file's contents (unless of course you know in advance how many records are there).

Comment: That is only true if the optimizer can trivially evaluate the first pass condition at compile time to convert `while` into `do ... while`.  Otherwise, the efficiency is different by a tiny amount.  If you are working on a tiny loop executed very few times that is nested inside a loop executed very many times, that efficiency difference may matter.  That situation is rare, but might be the focus of the question.

Comment: @jsf: this discussion is not quite relevant as the loops have different semantics and are not just interchangeable. I was essentially commenting on the "steady state" behavior. This said, I can't see practical situations where it would be advantageous to trade one type of loop for the other with some coding twists, as the optimizer might restructure things anyway.

Comment: The question asks about the efficiency difference, which tends to imply ignoring the semantic difference, which ought to imply a human can deduce that the body would be executed at least once either way.  Then the question is only interesting if the compiler can't make the same deduction.  Even then it is only interesting in the case I described in my first comment.  In real software engineering, I have run into that case and usefully fixed the performance flaw in someone else's code in that case.

Comment: @jsf: my answer doesn't use your hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

If the optimizer does not insert redundant code, a top checked loop is slower because of the extra jump required.  If the optimizer does insert redundant code, the top checked loop will be trivially slower because of the redundant code itself and because of its cache impact.

If the correct behavior is that the body is executed at least once, then a top checked loop is less efficient (by **more** than the cost of one extra execution of the condition).  But that still is usually not a reason to choose bottom checking on the basis of efficiency.  Choose the one that makes the code more understandable to a human maintainer.

Programmers are used to looking at `while` loops (top checked loops) in which the condition is trivially true (from a human point of view) on the first pass.  The loop is still more readable top checked.  If the first pass is so trivially true that even the compiler sees it (occurs less often than you might guess) then there is really no efficiency difference.

Often the condition you want to test cannot even be computed until once through the loop.  Then I find a bottom checked loop more readable.  The common practice of making dummy inputs to the condition in order to top check something trivially true, is just distracting.

Answer (score -1):

The do while loop ensures that the body of the loop executes at least once.

it depends on how much you need to use it, i saw this good example of when you need to use the do while loop

> Perhaps you've written a graphical program that runs an animation. When the game ends, you need to show your players the scoreboard. Of course, you need to run the animation loop at least once just to render the scoreboard. So: run your animation in the loop and do the conditional at the end to see if you should stop animating because the game is over.